# Why Difference between call_user_func and call_user_func_array() return types

Tags: php, callback

I was trying to get a clear difference between methods `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()` when I stumbled upon a difference in return types that wasn't apparent to me before.Consider the class **Test** with a method `dnd($t)`:

```
class Test {
function dnd($t) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($t);
    echo "</pre>";
  }
 }
```

Instantiate:

```
$obj = new Test();
$params = [33,22,'fff'];
```

Now calling by call_user_func method

```
call_user_func([$obj,'dnd'], $params);
```

This results in:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=>
     int(33)
 [1]=>
     int(22)
 [2]=>
     string(3) "fff"
 }
```

While call_user_func_array:

```
call_user_func_array([$obj,'dnd'], $params);
```

yields:

```
int(33)
```

Why this variation and what impact does it have on parameters passed to functions or function calls that rely on parameters?

Comment: `call_user_func_array` accepts array of parameters as a second argument, meaning that the first array item will become the first argument, the second item -- the second argument, etc.

Comment: Theres no difference in the "return types", as you don't return anything in dnd. There's only a difference in how the arguments are passed to the function

Comment: thanks for that clarification @Philipp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> call_user_func([$obj,'dnd'], $params)

This resolves to

```
$obj->dnd(array(33, 22, 'fff'))
```

while

> call_user_func_array([$obj,'dnd'], $params)

resolves to

```
$obj->dnd(33, 22, 'fff')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second parameter `call_user_func` receives the 'arguments' separately.
So our only argument is the **array**.

```
$t = [33,22,'fff']
```

The second parameter `call_user_func_array` receives the 'arguments' in the form of an array and sends them to the desired function.
As a result, the **first array index** is used as the only argument.

```
$t = int(33) // int(22) and 'fff' are the second and third arguments of the dnd() method (not defined here)
```